# Yii 1.1 create relationships automatically

Tags: php, web, yii, relationships

Pago, model exists in Yii. As I create relationships automatically?..

Example:

```
$pago = new Pago();
```

Now I want to show information:

```
echo $pago->iDTIPOTRAMITE->id;
```

It is assumed that the information must be loaded by default

thanks.

Comment: IF your database have correct relations (foreign keys), and your models were generated (gii for example), you can access to related data as you describe, but relation name should precede related attribute. Relation names are in protected/models/yourmodel.php, on 'relations' method. For example, if your model client have related model city, and you want city name related to client, you should use $client-> cities-> name

Comment: Yes, what you say is true for queries, but when is a new model, all relationships are null. There a way to automatically load all these relationships?.

Comment: Automatically, i don't know, because are defined previously on each implied model. With yii concept you first prepare your db and then genera te your models. When your db change with new tables, you should add new or update your models . Out of yii, if your db need dinamic structure in tables and records, you should consider to use noSQL dbs like Mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution here: [model init()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#init-detail)

With this method, set initial property values.

Example. Pago model.

```
public function init()
{
    $documentos = DocumentacionT::model()->findAll(array(
      'condition' => 'ID_TIPOSOLICITUD = :idTipo',
      'params' => array(':idTipo' => 5)
    ));

    $pagoDocumento = [];

    foreach($documentos as $documento)
    {
      $pagoDocumento[] = new PagoDocumento();
    }

    $this->pagoDocumentos = $pagoDocumento;
}
```